# Prove $n^\frac{1+2}{\sqrt{\log n}} = O(n \log n)$

Tags: calculus, asymptotics

Prove  that  $$n^\frac{1+2}{\sqrt{\log n}} = O(n\ \log n).$$

I want to compute the two growth rates by using L'Hôpital's rule:

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}  \frac{f(n)}{g(n)}$$

so I get something like this:

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{n^\frac{1+2}{\sqrt{\log n}}}{n\ \log n}$$

However the main trouble I'm having is differentiating $$ n^\frac{1+2}{\sqrt{\log n}}$$

What would be the best way to approach $f(n)$?

Thanks in advance, guys.

Comment: do you mean n^{1+2/sqrt{logn}} ?

Comment: ya that's the correct equation

Comment: Is it {1+2}/sqrt{n}? (=3/sqrt{n})?

Comment: its supposed to be 3/sqrt{log n} unless I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: @FireStorm: Then why was it written as $1+2$?  Note that when $n$ is big enough, $3/\sqrt{\log n}<1$, which already gives $O(n)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is same as to show $n^{\frac{2}{\sqrt{\log n}}}=O(\log n)$
I think it's wrong.
Let $n=e^{x^2}$, then it becomes $e^{2x}=O(x^2)$, 
But it's false..

Comment: The OP asked if $n^{3/\sqrt{\log n}} = O(n \log n)$ and this is in fact true. We even have $n^{3/\sqrt{\log n}} = o(n \log n)$.

Comment: Since when $ O(n\ \log n)$ is the same as $ O(\ \log n)$? How did this get 3 upvotes?

Answer (score 1):

Let

$$f(n) = n^{\frac{3}{\sqrt{\log n}}}.$$

Note that

$$ \begin{align}
\log f(n) &= \log n \frac{3}{\sqrt{\log n}},\\
\implies  \log f(n) &= 3 \sqrt{\log n},\\
\implies \log f(n) &\le 3 \frac{\log n}{3},\\
\implies f(n) &\le n.
\end{align}$$

Thus $f(n) = O(n)= O(n \log n)$.

Note that by replacing the bound in the last but one step by upper bounding $\sqrt{\log n}$ by  $\frac{\epsilon}{3} \log n$, gives us the $f(n) \le n^{\epsilon}$ for any $\epsilon > 0$.